# A simple example of a $G$-principal bundle that cannot be lifted to an $F$-principal bundle along an epimorphism $F\to G$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

I am trying to understand [spin structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure), in particular how they may fail to exist. To start with, I would like to see a most simple example of a [$G$-principal bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle) that *cannot* be lifted to an $F$-principal bundle along a given epimorphism $F\to G$.

Since it is written that all compact, orientable manifolds of dimension 3 or less are spin, I hope that there is an homomorphism $F\to G$ for which an example where liftings fail to exist is easier to construct and to understand than for $\operatorname{Spin}(n)\to SO_n$.

To be precise, I am asking for 3 things:

1. a principal $G$-bundle $E\to B$,
2. an epimomorphism of topological groups $F\to G$,
3. an argument that shows that there exist no principal $F$-bundle $D\to B$ such that the given principal $G$-bundle $E\to B$ could be viewed as its quotient by the action of the kernel of $F\to G$.

I hope I understand correctly that this would be "analogous" to the absence of spin structures.  If I am mistaken, I'll appreciate an explanation why not.

---

*Update.*

I have a conjecture that the $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$-principal bundle $S^2\to\mathbf{R}P^2$ with the epimorphism $\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ could be an example I am looking for.

Comment: Not totally sure I understand the question, but probably you're looking for the double-covering of the circle by the circle via the restriction of the complex squaring map, a.k.a., the non-trivial $O(1) = \{+1, -1\}$ principal bundle over the circle. (The $O(1)$ principal bundle over the circle induced by the [sic] homomorphism $O(1) \to SO(1)$ is the trivial bundle.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, if you tell me what you find confusing in my question, i can try to improve it. I am asking for 3 things: (1) a principal $G$-bundle $E\to B$, (2) an homomorphism of topological groups $F\to G$, (3) an argument that shows that there exist no principal $F$-bundle $D\to B$ such that the principal $G$-bundle $E\to B$ could be viewed as its quotient by the action of the kernel of $F\to G$. (I hope i understand correctly that this would be "analogous" to the absence of spin structures.)

Comment: My tentative guess, which seems to have been wrong from the clarification of your comment, was that you're seeking a principal $F$ bundle and a principal $G$ bundle over the same space where the $F$ bundle is not induced by the $G$ bundle together with a homomorphism $F \to G$. <> Incorporating your comment into the question seems advisable? Either way, I'll leave these comments for posterity.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, your $\mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ map is a perfect example.  Because there are two $\mathbb{Z}_2$s in play (the quotient, and the kernel), I'll use $K$ for the kernel and $Q$ for the quotient.

What you want to see is:

> There is no principal bundle $\mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow P\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ for which
> a)  $P/K \cong S^2$ and
> b)  $Q$ acts on $P/K$ via the antipodal map.

But, in fact, more is true:  asking for condition a) is already too much.

**Proposition**:  There is no principal bundle $\mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow P\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ for which condition a) above holds.

To see this, let's assume for a contradiction that we have such a principal bundle $\mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow P\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ for which the subaction by $K$ on $P$ has quotient $S^2$.

Now, $P$ must be a $4$-fold covering of $\mathbb{R}P^2$, so there are a few possibilities.

1. $P$ is a disjoint union of $4$ copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$
2. $P$ is a disjoint union of $2$ copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and one copy of $S^2$.
3. $P$ is a disjoint union of $2$ copies of $S^2$.

We will rule these out one at a time.

In case 1, because the quotient $P/\mathbb{Z}_4$ must be connected, it follows that $\mathbb{Z_4}$ permutes the copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ around.  But then $P/K$ is a disjoint union of two copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$, so is not $S^2$.  Thus, case 1 cannot occur.

In case 2, because each element of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ acts by a diffeomorphism on $P$, while $S^2$ and $\mathbb{R}P^2$ are *not* diffeomorphic, it follows that no element of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ maps a point in $S^2$ to a point in either copy of $\mathbb{R}P^2$.  In particular, the quotient $P/\mathbb{Z}_4$ is necessarily disconnected, so case 2 cannot occur either.

Thus, we are left with case 3.  We first claim that the element $1\in \mathbb{Z}_4 = \{0,1,2,3\}$ must interchange the two copies of $S^2$.  Indeed, because $1$ acts as a diffeomorphism on $P$ it either preserves both copies of $S^2$ or it interchanges them.  But $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_4$, so if *it* preserves both copies, then all of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ preserves both copies, which then gives a disconnected quotient $P/\mathbb{Z}_4$, a contradiction.

Now, because $1$ interchanges the two copies of $S^2$, it now follows that $2 = 1 + 1$ preserves the two copies of $S^2$.  But $2$ generates $K$, so now we reach the final contradiction that $P/K$ is disconnected, so is not diffeomorphic to $S^2$.